# Hiding an Advanced Custom Field based on Taxonomy Field selection

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I am trying to to show/hide one advanced custom field based on the ACF taxonomy field without any luck.  I have tried reworking [this example](http://www.elliotcondon.com/conditional-logic-for-advanced-custom-fields/) a bit to fit my needs but nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is for core Wordpress-related questions. It's best to ask the author of the plugin about things like this. Elliot over at ACF will be happy to help you, I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks, but there are many questions on here related to plugins, especially ACF, there is even a tag for it.  I have started to get it working and will post results as I get them.